# famo.us lightbox demo transition

Tags: lightbox, famo.us

I'm trying to get a transition that is similar to the lightbox demo that famous has put out. I have a grid layout, when I click a surface in the grid, Id like to have the surface transition, grow in size and be centered in the browser window.

--edit
Here is the demo, what I would like to nail is the flyout of the clicked image from its location to the center of the screen. http://demo.famo.us/lightbox/

I have the following code that I've been using as a basis. http://codepen.io/heyimlance/pen/JooQMX

```
var Engine = famous.core.Engine;
var Surface = famous.core.Surface;
var GridLayout = famous.views.GridLayout;
var StateModifier = famous.modifiers.StateModifier;
var Transform = famous.core.Transform;
var RenderNode = famous.core.RenderNode;
var Easing = famous.transitions.Easing;

var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

var grid = new GridLayout({
    dimensions: [8, 8],
});

var surfaces = [];

grid.sequenceFrom(surfaces);

function newSurface(id) {
    var surface = new Surface({
        content: id + 1,
        properties: {
            backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (id * 70 / 64) + ", 60%, 70%)",
            lineHeight: '50px',
            textAlign: 'center'
        }
    });

    var smod = new StateModifier({
      size: [50,50],
      transform: Transform.translate(0,0,1),
      origin: [.5,.5]
    });
    var rnode = new RenderNode();
    rnode.add(smod).add(surface);
    surfaces.push(rnode);

    surface.on('click', function() {
        console.log(smod)
        var zpos = (this.up || this.up == undefined) ? 0 : -180;
        if (!zpos) {

            this.up = false;
            smod.setTransform(Transform.translate(0,0,2000), { curve:Easing.outElastic, duration: 1000 })
            gridModifier.setTransform(Transform.translate(0,0,-2000), { curve:Easing.outElastic, duration: 500 })
        } else {
            this.up = true;
            gridModifier.setTransform(Transform.translate(0,0,0), { curve:Easing.outElastic, duration: 400 })
            smod.setTransform(Transform.translate(0,0,0), { curve:Easing.outElastic, duration: 1000 })

        }

    });
}

for(var i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    newSurface(i);
}

var gridModifier = new StateModifier({
    size: [400, 400],
    align: [.5, .5],
    origin: [.5, .5],
    transform : Transform.translate(0,0,0),
});

var gridRotate = new StateModifier({
    transform : Transform.rotate(0,0,0),
});


mainContext.add(gridModifier).add(grid);
mainContext.setPerspective(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, I made a few changes to use the `Lightbox` render contoller at the time of the click.  Not sure what transition you would like for the grid and surface, this should give you options to transition as you like.

**[Here is a codepen of the example](http://codepen.io/talves/pen/OPVXEv)**

#### The code:

```js
var Engine = famous.core.Engine;
var Surface = famous.core.Surface;
var GridLayout = famous.views.GridLayout;
var StateModifier = famous.modifiers.StateModifier;
var Transform = famous.core.Transform;
var RenderNode = famous.core.RenderNode;
var RenderController = famous.views.RenderController;
var Lightbox = famous.views.Lightbox;
var Easing = famous.transitions.Easing;

var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

var grid = new GridLayout({
  dimensions: [8, 8],
});

var surfaces = [];

var showing;

grid.sequenceFrom(surfaces);

var cmod = new StateModifier({
  origin: [0.5, 0.5],
  align: [0.5, 0.5]
});
var controller = new Lightbox({
  inTransition: true,
  outTransition: false,
  overlap: true
});
controller.hide();

function newSurface(id) {
  var surface = new Surface({
    size: [undefined, undefined],
    content: id + 1,
    properties: {
      backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (id * 70 / 64) + ", 60%, 70%)",
      lineHeight: '50px',
      textAlign: 'center',
      cursor: 'pointer'
    }
  });

  surface._smod = new StateModifier({
    size: [420,420],
    origin: [0.5, 0.5],
    align: [0.5, 0.5]
  });
  surface._rnode = new RenderNode();
  surface._rnode.add(surface._smod).add(surface);

  surfaces.push(surface);

  surface.on('click', function(context, e) {
    if (this === showing) {
      controller.hide({ curve:Easing.inElastic, duration: 1000 }, function(){
        gridModifier.setTransform(Transform.scale(1,1,1), 
            { curve:Easing.outElastic, duration: 1000 });
      });
      showing = null;
    } else {
      showing = this;
      gridModifier.setTransform(Transform.scale(0.001, 0.001, 0.001),
                        { curve:Easing.outCurve, duration: 300 });
      cmod.setTransform(Transform.translate(0, 0, 0.0001));
      controller.show(this._rnode, { curve:Easing.outElastic, duration: 2400 });
    }

  }.bind(surface, mainContext));
}

for(var i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
  newSurface(i);
}

var gridModifier = new StateModifier({
  size: [400, 400],
  align: [0.5, 0.5],
  origin: [0.5, 0.5]
});

mainContext.add(gridModifier).add(grid);
mainContext.add(cmod).add(controller);
mainContext.setPerspective(1000);
```

Comment: I actually did something similar to this as well. What I'm really trying to nail is the flyout of the surface from its position to the center of the screen. As seen in the demo.. http://demo.famo.us/lightbox/ I appreciate your answer though!

Comment: My answer is adequate enough to let you accomplish the fly out with some modifications.  Good luck!

Comment: When I used a similar lightbox solution, the element would pop back into place at the end of the animation. I'll play with it a bit more. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to follow "StateModifier" example that you can find in famo.us university : http://famo.us/university/lessons/#/famous-102/transitionables/2

Do a scale :

```
// animates x- and y-scale to 1
stateModifier.setTransform(
    Transform.scale(1, 1, 1),
    { duration : 2000, curve: Easing.outBack }
);
```

and then a align [0.5, 0.5] :

```
var alignModifier = new Modifier({
    align: [0.5, 0.5]
});
```

and if you want background to be minified, you have to apply 'scale' modifier too to make all other surfaces smaller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't think this will work. My grid layout which is centered within the page is affecting the surfaces alignment. I need to change the parent alignment from the grid to the page.

Comment: Your problem here is that your surfaces are in a grid. Right?
One solution can be to remove grid and to position surfaces with a "translate" modifier and to calculate [X,Y] in your controller.
If you do this, you can apply scale and align as i suggested above.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a gridlayout. I was thinking this but the grid is very useful for my needs. Thanks again!